# how does CXPACKETS relates to CXCONSUMER wait types?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, monitoring, wait-types

when running a delete query to a table  that has many foreign keys I get the following `waits`.

I noticed that I have both `CXPACKETS` and `CXCONSUMER` wait types at the same time during of the execution of my query.

the question is:

what is the relation between these 2 wait types (if any)?

[image]

Comment: Some interesting information here - [CXCONSUMER wait type – history and what you need to know](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/cxconsumer-wait-type-history-and-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: great article indeed `I’ve seen control threads show both CXCONSUMER and CXPACKET, depending on what’s happening in the query - Paul Randal`

Comment: >>>I noticed that I have both CXPACKETS and CXCONSUMER wait types at the same time<<< Your delete was executed in one session, and these two waits are from different sessions, and noone of these 2 blocks another session. There is no correlation between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- CXCONSUMER occurs when a consumer thread waits for a producer thread to send rows.
- CXPACKET occurs when trying to synchronize the query processor exchange iterator or getting a required buffer.

CXCONSUMER waits are generally benign, encountered as a normal part of parallel(CXPACKET) execution.